# MySQL : Is there a command similar to FLUSH STATUS to reset GLOBAL STATUS?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run some load tests on my MySQL server and check a bunch of relevant GLOBAL STATUS variables after each run.  Is there an easy way to flush GLOBAL STATUS variables like the regular FLUSH STATUS command?

Restarting the server seems to be one way of accomplishing the same thing but I'd prefer something faster.

Comment: There doesn't currently seem to be a way to flush ALL global status variables without a restart. Which ones are you specifically interested in?

Comment: currently would like to log variables like QCACHE, QUERIES, THREADS, ABORTED, READS
along with COM_DELETE, COM_INSERT, COM_SELECT, COM_UPDATE, MAX_USED_CONNECTIONS, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Try from command-line (not mysql prompt):

```
$ mysqladmin flush-status
```

Comment: looks like `mysqladmin flush-status` does not do what I expected it to. Back with more, but there was a very old feature request for this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22875

Comment: thanks for trying --- yeah saw that when googling around but figured it was either enabled by now or there were better ways of doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting. You may looking at the global variables the wrong way. Try using the session variables instead.

Here is an example: I ran the following commands in succession:

```
select sleep(1);
flush status;
select sleep(1);
show global status like 'com_select';
show session status like 'com_select';
```

He is what I got:

```
mysql> select sleep(1); flush status; select sleep(1); show global status like 'com_select'; show session status like 'com_select';
+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.01 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 25    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sleep(1); flush status; select sleep(1); show global status like 'com_select'; show session status like 'com_select';
+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 27    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sleep(1); flush status; select sleep(1); show global status like 'com_select'; show session status like 'com_select';
+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----------+
| sleep(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.01 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 29    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Com_select    | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As shown, Com_select will reset in your session but not globally, which actually makes sense in terms of global variables. In light of this, you must tailor your testing as follows:

- Never disconnect
- Stay in the same session
- FLUSH STATUS
- Start a new test in the same session

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Will try, thanks.  Some of the load testing overwhelms the db server and I might not be able to keep the connection but I suppose in that case I'd have the same problem with the global variables as well.